# Django and Redis package options

Tags: django, caching, redis

I am busy researching how best to incorporate Redis with my Django based site and am a bit confused when it comes to the available package options. Im trying to decide between:

- redis-py
- django-redis
- django-redis-cache

Under the hood, `django-redis` and `django-redis-cache` both use `redis-py`. So why don't I just use `redis-py` directly? I can't seem to figure out what the benefit of using one of the django packages are if I can simply `import redis` in my Django project and off I go.

I am busy going through the documentation, but can't seem to find anything that directly answers this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage of using one of the Django packages is that you then can then configure Redis as the Django cache backend, so you can use the [built-in cache API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/). Without that, you'll have to manage all the caching yourself directly with Redis.

An additional advantage is that you can also use redis as the session store.

Comment: Ok I see, makes sense. One last thing then, how would I go about about setting configuration options when using one of the Django packages. Would I still import redis in my settings.py file, and use config_set

Comment: Just to clarify the above question, I know you could just use the redis config file. But im referring to setting config options when Django starts up. (or is that simply not advised?)